# Cloudflare 520 Error

Tags: digital-ocean, cloudflare

I got an issue with Cloudflare at the moment. When pressing multiple image links at once (ctrl+click) Some pages return a 520. http://art.hespen.net (image links are, for example 'Most popular' or 'Latest Wallpapers') Opening around 5 links in new tabs at once, triggers it.

I don't think the IP whitelist is an issue, as I allow all: (digital ocean server)

```
<Directory "/dir">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The docs tell me to do a curl request, which always gave me a positive response.
I also got a har file from the 520 result: https://pastebin.com/uRDURENP

I don't know where to look anymore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was Imagick. I used Imagick to determine the resolution of the wallpaper on the image page. Which for some reason created a 520 error on some occasions.

Using the php function getImageSize, I have seemed to resolve the issue.